# How to recognize cross lines in opengl?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm trying to write a program in which I should recognize when 2 lines cross each other. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: OpenGL?  Why not [Bentley–Ottmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentley%E2%80%93Ottmann_algorithm)?

Comment: I should write my program by opengl. You mean that I implement this algorithm to recognize crossing lines ?

Comment: Correct.  Using OpenGL to detect intersections in image space won't be terribly accurate.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL is for *rendering* geometry. This is a simple mathematical problem which you don't need OpenGL to solve.  You would normally use algorithms in a geometry library or scene graph. CGAL has a nice writeup here:

- http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Sweep_line_2/Chapter_main.html